# Duda con Interfaz Grafica en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, interfaz-gráfica, material-design

Hola comunidad mi pregunta es sencilla, quisiera saber si hay alguna manera de realizar esta interfaz en python.

[image: Instalador de un software de AMD]

Y si es posible como puedo generar cambios asi en las ventanas con python... para poder crear estilos personalizados.

algo como los GUI skins de C# pero en python

Comment: Posiblemente lo puedas conseguir con kivy, pero me parece que tiene algunas restricciones para equipos que tengan opengl < 2.0. Si deseas distribuir tu aplicación esto sería un problema. Hay otras bibliotecas para hacer guis pero son de aspecto sencillo.

Comment: Hola Ángel, me temo que tu pregunta es demasiado vaga y amplia para el sitio, posible lo es. Aparte de Tkinter (que aunque bueno para apps sencillas es algo limitado), existen múltiples frameworks en Python para crear GUIs muy completas y potentes como PyQt-PySide(ambas usando Qt), PyGTK (GTK+), Kivy, wxPython, etc. Concuerdo con PAGANA en que al menos la interfaz que muestras es bastante simple de reproducir con [Kivy](https://kivy.org/#home).

Comment: Gracias Fjsevilla apenas empiezo en python, he visto algo sobre kivy.